# mongo's group results to panda's DataFrame

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, dataframe

Are there any convenience methods for loading results of a mongodb group operation into a pandas DataFrame?

Here's the type of grouping the mongo query does:

```
    '$group': {
        '_id': {'country': '$country', 'oem':'$oem'},
         'count': {'$sum': 1}
    }
```

This comes back as a list of dictionaries that look like the following:

```
[
   ...
   { "_id" : { "country" : "US", "oem" : "mmm" }, "count" : 595 },
   ...
]
```

I want this loaded into a DataFrame so that `country` and `oem` automatically become indexes.  Short of remapping the result, is there anything in the Pandas API that can already deal with this?  Or can I re-write the mongo query somehow so that it returns a structure that's friendlier to pandas APIs?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: a dataframe with three columns: `country`, `oem` and `count` (optionally indexed by `country` and `oem`)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [json_normalize()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
In [59]: l
Out[59]:
[{'_id': {'country': 'UA', 'oem': 'uuuu'}, 'count': 555},
 {'_id': {'country': 'US', 'oem': 'aaaa'}, 'count': 595},
 {'_id': {'country': 'DE', 'oem': 'bbbb'}, 'count': 777}]

In [60]: from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

In [61]: l
Out[61]:
[{'_id': {'country': 'UA', 'oem': 'uuuu'}, 'count': 555},
 {'_id': {'country': 'US', 'oem': 'aaaa'}, 'count': 595},
 {'_id': {'country': 'DE', 'oem': 'bbbb'}, 'count': 777}]

In [62]: json_normalize(l)
Out[62]:
  _id.country _id.oem  count
0          UA    uuuu    555
1          US    aaaa    595
2          DE    bbbb    777
```

setup:

```
l = [
   { "_id" : { "country" : "UA", "oem" : "uuuu" }, "count" : 555 },
   { "_id" : { "country" : "US", "oem" : "aaaa" }, "count" : 595 },
   { "_id" : { "country" : "DE", "oem" : "bbbb" }, "count" : 777 },
]
```